# How to get the redirect URL from a shortened one Jquery

Tags: jquery, url

Is it possible to grab the redirect URL from a shortened URL such as Bi.ty or t.co etc..

UPDATE:

I suppose I wasn't as clear as I should have been. This is what I want to do

```
var output =[];
var shorturl = "http://t.co"; //input shorturl

//Code I need!!! - make shorturl display long url version ie: http://twitter.com

var longurl = "http://twitter.com"; //result from above code

output.push('<p>' + longurl + '</p>'); //display http://twitter.com to the user
```

I don't want to redirect the user, I just want to be able to display the long url for each short url that is put into the code. If possible I want this to be done solely through jQuery

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this well, you want to parse the small url (i.e http://goo.gl/ktzOU) too his target (i.e [google.com](http://google.com)) ?

You'll have to use PHP **and** Javascript to do the task.

1) Do a PHP script who gets the new target by using [Curl](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/book.curl.php) and echoes it in the page

2) Do an [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call with jQuery who sends the small url to the previous PHP page

Done, enjoy !

After your comment, some more thoughs :

You can get json easily with [$.getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) (jQuery).

With php, just do [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php) on your json string.

Comment: That would work except the urls are being retrieved through a jQuery JSON request. It is possible to retrieve the JSON through PHP let me see if that works.

Comment: You can get json from jQuery easily, see [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) !

Answer (score 0):

I think jQuery should handle redirection, so if you use the shortened URL you should be redirected transparently to the target url.

For example `$('#id').load('<shortened url>')` should load the target html.

If not, than you can check the response HTTP status code:

```
complete: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
     if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 301) 
     { 
        // redirect
     }
     else
     {
     }
  }
```

Comment: I don't want to redirect them to the target url I want to print out the target url on the page.

Comment: Than check the status code as in the second part of my answer.